# How to set Arguments for Cmder in C# Process

Tags: c#, cmder

I want to set arguments for Cmder in C# Process. This is my code but it not working,

```
Process Run = new Process();                 
Run.StartInfo.FileName = @"Cmder.exe";                  
Run.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x -run python";
Run.Start();
```

[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd2tD.png)

How can i make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Put C# to the side. Open up a standard Windows command prompt. What _exact_ thing do you type in there to get the outcome you want? And **does it work there**?

Comment: Yes, Cmd work properly

Comment: What _exact_ thing do you type in there to get the outcome you want?

Comment: when i type "python", in cmd it goes into  python environment.specific i change Arguments="/c python"

Comment: So why is `cmder` involved? Why not run python _directly_ rather than `Cmder.exe`?

Comment: Cmder is nicer, I want to replace Cmd with Cmder, when the button is clicked, Cmder will automatically enter to Python

Comment: OK, so open up a standard windows Command Prompt. What _exact_ thing do you type in to get the outcome you want? _You can't just say "python" since that doesn't load `cmder.exe`._

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not good at English, but I want Process to run Cmder.exe and run the command set up, the problem is that I don't know how to write the argument correctly with Cmder. 
When I open Cmder and type "python" it works fine